# Visual Studio Conversion Properties: "set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed" problem

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I converted a `VS2008` project to `VS2019` and I now get these messages below.  This is typical and I've looked up various methods online (even here on StackOverflow) to try and solve it but the solutions never work.  I have to end up creating all new projects but there are too many on this upgrade.   How do I get to the bottom of figuring out how to fix it?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(39,5): warning MSB4211: The property "IntermediateOutputPath" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets (38,5)".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.BuildSteps.Targets(30,5): warning MSB4211: The property "DebugType" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.BuildSteps.Targets (29,5)".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(373,5): warning MSB4211: The property "CleanFile" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets (38,5)".
```

TIA!!

Comment: Well, exiting all instances of VS2019 in this case fixed itself.   Weird.